# See size of Windows 10 updates

Tags: windows, internet-connection, windows-update, windows-10-preview

If I was on a metered connection, I would probably want to know how large each update is when updating through Windows Update.

How can I see the size of each update that Windows 10 is downloading & installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download this third party software which will let you see the update size:
https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-see-size-of-windows-10-updates/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

With the Windows 10TP you have little control over the updates. Since it is a test version, Microsoft updates it automatically so that everybody is on the same page.

The size of updates will depend on what it is. For 'normal' updates the sizes are similar to Windows 7 - meaning an update of the Defender definition files is a few KBs and an update of e.g. Silverlight or Net Framework may be 100 or more MBs.

But the real biggies are the new builds. The last build 10074 was 2.5GBs for the ESD (the installation file) and the prior builds were in that same order of magnitude. And those you get too on a regular appr. monthly basis

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So we can assume that when windows 10 comes out, it will display more information about the updates it's installing then?

Comment: Right now it is not clear what the exact update facilities will be after RTM. They removed the update links from Control Panel to the new UI and right now I do not see the same options as e.g. in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

**Set your connection as a metered connection.**

To do this Click on the wifi icon in taskbar and choose your connection. There's a link named "properties" . Click on it .Then your connection properties will appear. There's a button named as "Set as metered connection". Turn it on and your connection will be a metered connection.

Go to Windows Update setting and check for updates.  This won't probably download the update but tells you what is the size of the update:
[image: Update Settings window]

Comment: How do you “set your connection as a metered connection”?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will be helpful but look at this picture

[image]

I think you can locate to this place via the control panel(then System and Security and Windows update), or by using the search in the start menu.

Comment: It won't be helpful.  Windows Update has been removed from Control Panel in Windows 10.

Comment: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-build-9926-wheres-windows-update Take a look at this. Also it depends on your build

Comment: @LukeWoodward - Hasn't been removed just moved.